# Split on delimiter except when followed by space

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to split a string, keeping the delimiters, except when the delimiter is followed by a space.  I seem to be most of the way there, except that the character immediately following the delimiter is retained with the delimiter.

What I have so far is the following:

```
>>> s='\nm222 some stuff \n more stuff'
>>> re.split('(\n[^ ])',s)
['', '\nm', '222 some stuff \n more stuff']
```

The result i need is

```
['', '\n', 'm222 some stuff \n more stuff']
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty You're correct - my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
>>> s='\nm222 some stuff \n more stuff'
>>> re.split(r'(\n(?! ))', s)
['', '\n', 'm222 some stuff \n more stuff']
```

Your code,

```
re.split('(\n[^ ])',s)
```

Doesn't work because `(\n[^ ])` puts the "not a space" character in the same capturing group as `\n`, giving you `\nm`.  `(\n(?! ))` avoids consuming the "not a space" character, placing it in the next capturing group but still using it to split.

You can read more about lookaheads on the [python regex documentation page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use `\n(?! )`. This is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

This will ensure the `\n` is not followed by a space

---

If you wanted, you could even use `\n(?!\s)`. `\s` includes a variety of whitespace characters like

- `' '` (a single space)
- `\t` (tab)
- `\n` (newline)
- `\r` (carriage return)

Answer (score 0):

You need a lookahead assertion.

```
re.split('(\n(?=[^ ]))', s)
```

Comment: You should be using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)